# how to pass selected drop-down list value to a variable or data block to execute a query

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a form and  I  a dropdown pop-list with year values in it(year field is not a primary key).
I have to fill all other field values when i select a year from dropdown(need to execute query of data block).
how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If that dropdown list is part of the data block (it doesn't matter whether it is or is not a primary key), then

- navigate to that block
- enter query mode
- select year
- execute query

---

If dropdown belongs to another (control?) block, then

- in Forms Builder, open data block `year` field's property palette and set "Copy value from item" property to `CTRL_BLOCK.YEAR`

  - alternatively, create a data block-level `pre-query` trigger:

    ```
    :data_block_name.year := :control_block.year;
    ```
- create a button (in control block)
- create a `when-button-pressed` trigger which will

  ```
  go_block('data_block_name');
  execute query;
  ```
- run the form
- select year
- push the button

Comment: If i do as above it is giving data of all years and not the one I selected

Comment: Is there any way to store the selected dropdown value into a variable. I can use it to run conditional execute_query

Comment: And i have to populate data on two conditions one is selecting  year from dropdown and other is code_value

Comment: If it didn't work, then you most probably did something wrong. Can't tell what, I don't have your tables, data nor form. Selected dropdown value is contained in that field, no need for additional variables. I have no idea what "code_value" is, but it would work just the same as the "year" condition.